# Jquery UI Accordion - Hide header border for active element

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am creating a Jquery accordion from the following HTML

```
<div class="title"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Title goes here</a></div>
<div class="body">Body goes here</div>
```

The accordion works and has a border around it which I like. However, when an element is expanded, I would like to remove the bottom border of the header. Is this possible? For an example of what I need, try

```
<div class="title" style="border-bottom:0px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Title goes here</a></div>
<div class="body">Body goes here</div>
```

I need the above style but only for the active element in the accordion. I tried setting the style for

```
.ui-accordion-header-active
```

but it does not work. Any ideas?

Edit: here is a Js fiddle to test it. I'd like to get rid of the dividing line between title and body.

http://jsfiddle.net/2LkS6/

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the following css:

```
.ui-accordion-header-active {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LkS6/1/)

Comment: works on the fiddle but doesnt work in my code. I wonder if there is something else going on here.

Comment: inspect the element in the chrome console and you can see which styles get applied. I'd guess that you also have to add !important behind that style to force the overwrite or somehow tweak your css ordering

Comment: I revisited this topic today and wanted to post an update. I created a new theme using the theme roller and found to my surprise that none of my new styles were being applied. This is probably why your solution did not work initially. After a bit of digging, I found that Chrome was aggressively caching the CSS. I had to close Chrome and stop and restart my Visual studio debugger for the CSS changes to take effect. Once I did that, your solution works perfectly even without the !important in the style.